# Процедура, поиск по параметру

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!
У меня процедура:

```sql
USE [Fstp]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE Report
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime,
    @client nvarchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT 
        (case when oa.id is not null then 
                 (case when c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_privs' then cp.fio
                 when c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_ent' then ce.jur_name   end)
               else (case when mst_c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_privs'  then  case when ma.role_participant_type=2 then mst_cip.name else mst_cp.fio end
                  when mst_c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_ent' then mst_ce.jur_name  end)  end) as 'Страхователь', 
        ISNULL(convert(Varchar(10),oa.policy_date,104), convert(Varchar(10),ma.PolicyDate,104)) as policy_date
        FROM
    dbo.DOCS d 
    inner JOIN ogpo_application oa ON oa.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
    inner join docs_policy dp on dp.docs_id=d.DOCS_ID
    left join clients c on oa.insurer_id=c.CLIENTS_ID
         left join cl_privs cp on c.CLIENTS_ID=cp.CL_PRIVS_ID
         left join cl_ent ce on c.CLIENTS_ID=ce.CL_ENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN mst_application ma ON ma.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
    left join mst_docs_policy mdp on mdp.docs_id=d.DOCS_ID
    left join clients mst_c on ma.insurer_id=mst_c.CLIENTS_ID
        left join cl_privs mst_cp on mst_c.CLIENTS_ID=mst_cp.CL_PRIVS_ID
        left join client_IPKH mst_cip on mst_cip.clients_id=mst_c.CLIENTS_ID and mst_cip.is_history=0
        left join cl_ent mst_ce on mst_c.CLIENTS_ID=mst_ce.CL_ENT_ID

Where (policy_date  between @StartDate AND @EndDate) and
('Страхователь' = '' or 'Страхователь' = @client)
```

Мне надо поиск по `policy_date` и `'Страхователь'`. В данном запросе поиск не идет. `'Страхователь' = @client` мне кажется так неправильно. 
Как в случае условии case конструкции приравнять параметр?

Comment: @ Zufir, в таблице нет поля "Страхователь". Страхователь берется с таблиц clients(clients_id,...), cl_privs(FIO, Cl-privs_id) и  из нескольких таблиц

Comment: В данном случаи Страхователь - псевдоним

Comment: Да, уже понял, исправился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` парсится до `SELECT`, так что в нем нельзя обращаться к колонкам по алиазу. Есть два варианта:

Обернуть в еще один селект:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (ваш SELECT без WHERE) restable
WHERE (policy_date  between @StartDate AND @EndDate) and
      ([Страхователь] = '' or [Страхователь] = @client)
```

Использовать CTE:

```sql
;WITH restable as 
    (ваш SELECT без WHERE)
SELECT * FROM restable 
WHERE (policy_date  between @StartDate AND @EndDate) and
      ([Страхователь] = '' or [Страхователь] = @client)
```

оба варианта c точки зрения SQL Server эквивалентны подстановки всего `CASE` в `WHERE`

Answer (score 3):

1. Не используйте русские имена полей.
2. Если уж использовали - указывайте их не в кавычках, а в квадратных скобках: `as [Страхователь]`, `[Страхователь] = '' or [Страхователь] = @client`
3. Заверните кейс в outer apply и в условии ссылайтесь на него. Как-нибудь так:

   ```sql
   SELECT insurInfo.Name, insurInfo.policy_date
       FROM
   dbo.DOCS d 
   inner JOIN ogpo_application oa ON oa.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
   inner join docs_policy dp on dp.docs_id=d.DOCS_ID
   left join clients c on oa.insurer_id=c.CLIENTS_ID
        left join cl_privs cp on c.CLIENTS_ID=cp.CL_PRIVS_ID
        left join cl_ent ce on c.CLIENTS_ID=ce.CL_ENT_ID
   LEFT JOIN mst_application ma ON ma.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
   left join mst_docs_policy mdp on mdp.docs_id=d.DOCS_ID
   left join clients mst_c on ma.insurer_id=mst_c.CLIENTS_ID
       left join cl_privs mst_cp on mst_c.CLIENTS_ID=mst_cp.CL_PRIVS_ID
       left join client_IPKH mst_cip on mst_cip.clients_id=mst_c.CLIENTS_ID and mst_cip.is_history=0
       left join cl_ent mst_ce on mst_c.CLIENTS_ID=mst_ce.CL_ENT_ID
       outer apply (select (case when oa.id is not null then 
                (case when c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_privs' then cp.fio
                when c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_ent' then ce.jur_name   end)
              else (case when mst_c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_privs'  then  case when ma.role_participant_type=2 then mst_cip.name else mst_cp.fio end
                 when mst_c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_ent' then mst_ce.jur_name  end)  end) as Name, ISNULL(convert(Varchar(10),oa.policy_date,104), convert(Varchar(10),ma.PolicyDate,104)) as policy_date) InsurInfo 
   Where (InsurInfo.policy_date  between @StartDate AND @EndDate) and 
         (InsurInfo.Name = '' or InsurInfo.Name = @client)
   ```

Comment: У меня нет в таблице поля Страхователь это псевдоним

Comment: а  как  policy_date?

Comment: поместите его в тот же InsurInfo и обращайтесь через insurInfo.policy_date. поправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Как написал Zuffir, лучше не использовать русский имена полей и псевдонимы.
Но в целом можно оставить, как есть, заменив только на условие

```
([Страхователь] = '' or [Страхователь] = @client)
```

Или даже на

```
(Страхователь = '' or Страхователь = @client)
```

Но в целом, рекоменудю пересмотреть немного запросы, т.к. лучше фильтровать по основным столбцам таблицы, а не по результатам вложенных запросов. Иначе будут проблемы с производительностью.

**UPD**
Раз это не вложенный запрос, то можно продублировать логику вычислимого поля. Получится что-то вроде:

```
(oa.id is not null and ((c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_privs' and cp.fio = @client) or 
(c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_ent' and ce.jur_name = @client))) 
or (oa.id is null and ((mst_c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_privs' and 
((ma.role_participant_type<>2 and mst_cp.fio = @client) or 
(ma.role_participant_type=2 and mst_cip.name = @client))) or 
(mst_c.CLIENTS_CLASS='cl_ent' and mst_ce.jur_name = @client)))
```

Comment: в WHERE нельзя обращаться к колонкам по алиазам - в этом как раз суть вопроса

Comment: Хм, да. Что-то я решил, что это вложенный запрос.